# Cloud based server for PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3, cloud-hosting

I plan to open a subscription based website that will be video and image heavy. I have the video and image hosting sorted using Amazons S3 and CDN. now, I will still need a *main* server to host php/html files and the mysql database.

My question is, is there a scalable solution (that has redundancy incase of spikes) to replace my main server so that I can still server my php and sql processes, but have it's resources increase on demand like the Amazon S3 service does for static files?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are called VPS; virtual private servers. At our company, HostGator's VPS serve us well, and they're cheaper than alternatives.

http://www.hostgator.com/vps-hosting/

Edit: You can change resources on demand, increasing and decreasing, without any modification from your part.

Oh, and by the way, if you need a really good service, there's Rackspace Cloud Servers. They're not exactly cheap though ;). However, if you can afford them, you won't regret this.

Comment: Are there any Europe based services?

Comment: Both HostGator and Rackspace have data centers around the world to tackle latency. I think Rackspace are better than HostGator about this.

Comment: Linode.com have servers based in London.

Answer (score 0):

VPSes aren't going to scale in the same way that you're thinking of (hand-off). VPSes are just virtualized servers... you still have to manage them like any other server.

If you want a managed server, those are expensive, but will be more hands-off.

I recommend you evaluate this service though: http://phpfog.com/. If you've heard of Heroku in the Ruby webapps world, it's like that but for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

On AWS you can also find scalable cloud hosting solutions. But on such a IaaS (Infastructure as a Service) provider you have to take care of some sysadmin stuff yourself. You might be better advised with a PaaS (Platform as a Service). This is a kind of abstraction layer on top of cloud technology – simplifying things for you.

We are currently developing such a service for developers in Europe ourselves. We have just posted a comparison of different providers here:

- http://blog.fortrabbit.com/comparing-cloud-hosting-platforms/

Comment: Hi, Frank. We don't mind people promoting their products but it does say in the FaQ that you dislose your link to any product mentioned as the community will likely flag it as spam.